# How to manage static content in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, static, content-management-system

I'm running a rails app for interactive learning for kids. We also have quite a few static pages like, landing pages, team pages, case studies etc. This is also deployed in the same rails app.

I would like a easy way for my team to manage the content without depending on the tech team. I can build an admin interface to edit these pages, but I don't want to recreate a CMS. I  checked out  Jekyll but the markdown syntax makes some tech novices uneasy.

Someone suggested using weebly/ wordpress and host it in a subdomain. I don't want to go overboard and add an additional layer of maintenance to the app.

I've a mongoid project and would appreciate any mongoid gems.

Comment: I have also had the similar issue.If these are just static pages and the layout is fixed or there are marginal changes then you can give a tinymce editor to the user where they can change the content of the page and save that into the DB. And in the views just render the content

Comment: you might want to checkout: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa - rails cms, but I think you can set it up to run inside your normal rails app, just route the cms to `/content`

Comment: I had made a website full of static stuff. The layouts were always constant and only the content changed hence I just used text files as source. not exactly a solution I guess. Just sharing

Answer (score 0):

[RefineryCMS](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms) is a popular content management solution for Rails apps. You can add it to your existing Rails app, as [described in the guide](http://refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app). RefineryCMS is targeted at the end user experience, you don't need extensive technological knowledge to use it.

There's an online demo of the CMS [which you can find here](http://demo.refinerycms.com/). You don't have to edit the pages using Markdown, it has a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor as well.

If you're looking for another CMS, you can find other solutions quite easily with [the Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/content_management_systems).

Answer (score 0):

Having had those exact same requirements i finally wrote a tool to manage the data/content and images

https://github.com/FeenixMakers/merged/

It edits yaml files from which it creates pages via developer (and pre-) defined templates. All data/images in git, but editable by point and click.
Deploys by hand (or mina really)

(i know this topic is super old, but it was still first search result for my terms, hence..)